# How to set class with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have that code
`<div id="first">`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`</div>`
`<div id="second">`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`</div>`
`<div id="third">`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`<li class="work"></li>`
`</div>`
How can i add the extra class to work with javascript -> need to be like this

`<div id="first">`
`<li class="work first"></li>`
`<li class="work second"></li>`
`<li class="work last"></li>`
`</div>`

Comment: Note that your html structure is invalid. li cannot be child of a div, you may want to use ul.

Comment: How is that jQuery question a duplicate of this? I see no mention of jQuery here.

Comment: Yes there is no jquery marked in the tags. So marking it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ele = document.getElementById('first').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
 {

      ele[i].className += ' '+'WhateverClassYouWant';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is to stay the same, using jquery something in this direction should work.

```
$('#first li').first().addClass('first')
$('#first li').nth-child(2).addClass('second')
$('#first li').last().addClass('last')
```

Also, a generic code in comments by PSL is certainly excellent way to go.